# quickbooks php sdk class not found

Tags: php, sdk, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require "vendor/autoload.php";
use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\Invoice;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\PurchaseOrder;



$dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
         'auth_mode' => 'oauth1',
         'consumerKey' => " ", 
         'consumerSecret' => " ",
         'accessTokenKey' => " ",
         'accessTokenSecret' => " ",
         'QBORealmID' => "",
         'baseUrl' => "https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/"
));

for($i = 1; $i<= 3; $i ++){
   $LineObj = Line::create([
       "Id" => $i,
       "LineNum" => $i,
       "Description" => "Pest Control Services",
       "Amount" => 35.0,
       "DetailType" => "SalesItemLineDetail",
       "SalesItemLineDetail" => [
           "ItemRef" => [
               "value" => "1",
               "name" => "Pest Control"
           ],
           "UnitPrice" => 35,
           "Qty" => 1,
           "TaxCodeRef" => [
               "value" => "NON"
           ]
       ]
   ]);
   $lineArray[] = $LineObj;
}
//Add a new Invoice
$theResourceObj = PurchaseOrder::create([
     "Line" =>  $lineArray,
    "CustomerRef"=> [
     "value"=> "1"
     ],
      "BillEmail" => [
            "Address" => "Familiystore@intuit.com"
      ],
      "BillEmailCc" => [
            "Address" => "a@intuit.com"
      ],
      "BillEmailBcc" => [
            "Address" => "v@intuit.com"
      ]
]);
?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Line' not found in /var/www/html/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK-master/Test2.php:24

**purchaseOrder.php:**

```
<?php

//require "vendor/autoload.php";
include('src/config.php');

use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\Invoice;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\PurchaseOrder;

// OBOT Data service
$dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
       'auth_mode' => 'oauth1',
         'consumerKey' => " ",
         'consumerSecret' => " ",
         'accessTokenKey' => " ",
         'accessTokenSecret' => " ",
         'QBORealmID' => " ",
         'baseUrl' => "https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/" 
));

$linedet = new IPPPurchaseOrderItemLineDetail();
$linedet->CustomerRef  = 86;

$line = new IPPLine();
$line->Id = 0;
$line->Description = 'test purchase order';
$line->Amount = 2.00;
$line->DetailType= 'ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail ';
$line->ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail = $linedet;
$line->BillableStatus = 'Notbillable';
$line->ItemRef = '19';
$line->UnitPrice = '25';
$line->Qty = '1';

$purchaseOrder = new IPPPurchaseOrder();
$purchaseOrder->Line = $line;
$purchaseOrder->VendorRef = 85;
$purchaseOrder->APAccountRef = 1;
$purchaseOrder->TotalAmt = 200.00;
$result = $dataService->Add($purchaseOrder); //add purchase order

?>
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'IPPPurchaseOrderItemLineDetail' not found in /var/www/html/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK-master/purchaseOrder.php:20

Why am I getting these errors? is the autoload not working? should I just directly include the class files that I need?

Comment: Who knows when you haven't shown us your autoloader?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: added the autoloader @Peter Featherstone

Comment: I didnt mean the auto generated autoloader, I meant your composer.json mapping

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by mapping, but I found composer.json. Sorry I'm new to this. @Peter Featherstone

Comment: That is composer.json from your quickbooks module... where is your composer.json that loads your files? How are you including the file that includes IPPPurchaseOrderItemLineDetail?

Comment: Okay so thats what I'm missing. how do I make a composer.json that will load IPPPuchaseOrderLineDetail? I had just assumed the autoloader loaded all the classes i needed. Thanks so much by the way I've been stuck on this for a while now @Peter Featherstone

Comment: That's a whole subject in itself but you can check out their docs which will show you how :-) https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: include "vendor/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/src/Data/IPPLine.php"; Is this basically what composer.json does? @Peter FeatherStone

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean. Composer is a package dependency manager at heart but you can use it for autoloading your own projects using PSR-4 or similar naming standards...

Comment: what I mean is: if I just go through and include all the classes that I need, why do I still get the same error? https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK and the github doesn't say anything about needing another autoloader to utilize its classes and it provides a full tutorial on getting started with the sdk. The point of the autoloader that is included in the sdk is to load all of the classes, right? anyways I added the classloader if that makes any difference. @Peter FeatherStone

Comment: I dont know what you mean and Ive never used that library so I have no idea. Are Line and IPPPurchaseOrderItemLineDetail, QuickBook classes or custom? I don't see you referencing them anywhere in your code, either through an include or a use statement...

Comment: I've added an answer based on what you've said as to what I think your problem is. I just think you are not declaring that you want to use the specific classes.

Comment: yeah, it works thanks so much @Peter Featherstone

Comment: I dont have enough points for my upvote to show publically but I accepted it @Peter Featherstone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards your first error below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Line' not found in /var/www/html/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK-master/Test2.php:24

I don't see you including the `Line` class anywhere, from the GitHub page [here](https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK#connecting-to-the-quickbooks-online-api) I have truncated their advice:

**Connecting to the QuickBooks Online API**

Currently the below API entity Endpoints support creating Objects from Array:

- Estimate
- ***Line***
- Invoice
- Item

For create/update above entity endpoints, you are going to import corresponding facade class:

```
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\{Facade_Class_Name};
```

As such you need to update your first script to include this Facade, which should be as simple as:

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\Invoice;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\PurchaseOrder;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\Line; // <-- You are missing this line
```

In regards the second error below:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'IPPPurchaseOrderItemLineDetail' not found in /var/www/html/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK-master/purchaseOrder.php:20

From searching the GitHub codebase again I can see this class is declared [here](https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK/blob/034204bf1e00ebd17fd80a7ac9ab15d76475d3e6/src/Data/IPPPurchaseOrderItemLineDetail.php). Therefore it should be as simple as declaring this again in your `use` statements at the top of the file that is using this, such as below:

```
<?php

//require "vendor/autoload.php";
include('src/config.php');

use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\Invoice;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\PurchaseOrder;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPPurchaseOrderItemLineDetail; // <-- You are missing this line
```

Looking at the rest of your code there seems to be a lot of classes that you are not declaring through `use` statements such as `PurchaseOrder`, `IPPLine` and `IPPPurchaseOrder` which you will also need to include.